# Neo4j better works on Linux or windows?

Tags: linux, windows, neo4j, installation

I want to start working with neo4j on a big project.
Since it is written in Java, it is not suppose to matter weather it is running on a Linux machine or a windows one.

I read all kind of things and really want to know what is right and what are the reasons to the answer and what may be the differences.

Thank you,
R.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of Java is *portability*. Any Java application should be able to run on any platform with a JVM, at least in theory. Hence, it should not matter.

Comment: Still, the winds are blowing in the Linux direction. Saying it works better and not price wise. I can't find justifications to that nor to windows installation.

Comment: @user3495363, try Linux. In my opinion, it is much easier to program in.

Comment: I guess I have no problem programming for both - java / .net. I just want to know what is more native/more right/ more light/more fast etc. what woul any of you do if you could chose (saying you don't prefer this language or an other)

Comment: @user3495363, I have little experience in .NET, but a quick DuckDuckGo search reveals that it is Windows-only. For portabilty, I'd recommend Java.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you're right.

Windows has some peculiarities in terms of memory mapping files and handling RAM that show up sometimes as weird performance behavior.

One important aspect is, that memory-mapping-RAM is taken from **inside** your Java heap. On all other systems its from the outside. So you have to provide more heap to Neo4j on Windows.

There is also some weird behavior in terms of file locking and concurrent file access.

Best is to performance test your use-cases and ask here on SO.

Comment: Thank you very much!
For some reason I didn't see your answer up until not too long ago.
Meanwhile I got an official answer from Neo tech team-

I'm posting it here in case it helps anyone and to approve your post as well :-)

Comment: Part 1:

The core difference between Linux and Windows installations of Neo4j
is that the "mapped memory cache"
(http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-caches.html#_file_buffer_cache)
is located off-heap on Linux. On windows, it's part of the java heap.
For large graphs and high requirements in terms of read operations,
you're better of using Linux and benefitting from the off-heap MMIO
layer.

Comment: Part 2: 

On the other hand sind, the windows package we provide comes with a
nice installer and a UI to start, stop and manage your graph database.
So this is very well suited for beginners and development machines.